# Empty string in mixed column nullifies a row when loaded using Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, inference

Consider the following JSON:

```js
{"col1": "yoyo", "col2": 1.5}
{"col1": "",     "col2": 6}
{"col1": "456",  "col2": ""}
{"col1": 444,    "col2": 12}
{"col1": null,   "col2": 1.7}
{"col1": 3.14,   "col2": null}
```

which I load using (Py)Spark as follows:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.json("my.json")
df.show()
```

which yields:

```
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|yoyo| 1.5|
|    | 6.0|
|null|null|  <---===***
| 444|12.0|
|null| 1.7|
|3.14|null|
+----+----+
```

I'm having hard time to understand why does the 3rd line is nullified.
It seems like the reason is that the only string in the second column is the empty string `""` and this somehow causes the nullification.
Note that `col1` contains an empty string at the 2nd row as well, but the row is *not* nullified.

For me, this is a very confusing and unexpected behaviour.
I was not able to find hints in the documentation.

- Is this behaviour expected? Why is it happening this way?
- I would expect the 3rd row to hold the string `"456"` for `col1` and the empty string `""` for `col2`. How can I achieve this behaviour (which feels much more natural to me)?

Comment: `inferSchema` to `false`, it is treated as int columns and ignored string values I think.

Comment: `inferSchema` does not seem to be an argument of `read.json`

Comment: @Dror: Using `primitivesAsString` would be the correct option here as I added to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It's not possible to mix different data types** in a single column when using Spark.

When reading the json file, Spark will try to infer the data type of each column (see the note at the bottom for more details). Here, Spark believes `col1` to be of string type and `col2` to be double. This can be confirmed by reading the json file and using `printSchema` on the dataframe.
This means that the data is the parsed based on these inferred data types. Spark will therefore try to parse `""` as a double which obviously fails. (For the second row in `col1` it works since `col1` is inferred to be of string type, `""` is therefore a valid input.)

When using `spark.read.json` it's possible to set different modes. From the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.json) we have:

> **mode** -
>   allows a mode for dealing with corrupt records during parsing. If None is
>   set, it uses the default value, `PERMISSIVE`.
>
> - `PERMISSIVE`: when it meets a corrupted record, puts the malformed string into a field configured by columnNameOfCorruptRecord, and sets other fields to null. To keep corrupt records, an user can set a string type field named columnNameOfCorruptRecord in an user-defined schema. If a schema does not have the field, it drops corrupt records during parsing. When inferring a schema, it implicitly adds a columnNameOfCorruptRecord field in an output schema.
> - `DROPMALFORMED`: ignores the whole corrupted records.
> - `FAILFAST`: throws an exception when it meets corrupted records.

From the above, we can see that `PERMISSIVE` mode is used by default and that if a corrupted record is encountered, all fields are set to `null`. This is what happens in this case. To confirm, it's possible to set `mode` to `FAILFAST`,

```
spark.read.json("my.json", mode='FAILFAST')
```

which would give an exception.

This could be solved by not inferring the data types and reading everything as strings instead.

```
spark.read.json("my.json", primitivesAsString='true')
```

---

**Note:** The schema inference for json is a bit different compared to other sources such as csv and txt, see [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/json/JsonInferSchema.scala#L114). For json files, both `""` and `null` have special handling to deal with json generators that do not differentiate between the two. For csv files, a column with an empty string `""` would still make the whole column be inferred to be string but this will not be the case for json.

As a side note, replacing `""` with e.g. `"5"` in `col2` will make the inferred column type be string.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful answer. There's still one missing part, why the 2nd line in the OP is _not_ nullified? It also contains an empty string for `col1` field.

Comment: @Dror: `col1` is actually inferred to be of string type so `""` is a valid input. I added this to the answer as well to make it clearer.

Comment: But _why_? Why does Spark believes that `col1` contains strings and thus excepts the `""`? It is not due to the order of rows in the JSON (I tried to swap 1st and 4th lines) and still the empty string in `col1` didn't harm the whole row.

Comment: @Dror: The inference is not that simple. Actually if you change `""` to `"5"` in `col2` then the inferred type for that column will be string as well. I tried to check a bit more in-depth and it appears that `null` and `""` are handled differently due to some json generators not differentiating the two. See the comment in the code here: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/json/JsonInferSchema.scala#L114

Comment: I noticed that and this what made me so confused! It's worthy to add that piece of information to your answer because I'm sure I'm not the only one who finds this surprising.

Comment: @Dror: I added that part as well. Hope it is clear enough (you are welcome to edit it if you think something is missing).